# Array to String conversion in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, string, codeigniter

I am getting the following error in my Codeigintor install which I can't seem to solve

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: models/upload_model.php

Line Number: 69
```

Here is my code:

```php
foreach($data as $field){
  $query = $this->db->get_where('Ushers', array('Date' => $field['Date']));
  $result_array = $query->row_array();
  if(empty($result_array)){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('Ushers_teams', array('Team' => $field['Team']));
    $ushers = $query->result_array();
    $doublebooking = FALSE;
    foreach($ushers as $usher){
      $columns = $this->db->list_fields('worship'); 
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM worship WHERE worship.Date LIKE '".$field['Date']."%'"; 
      foreach($columns as $column){ 
      $sql .= " OR worship.".(string)$column." = '".(string)$usher."'"; 
    } 
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    $usher = $result->result_array();
    if(!isEmpty($usher)) $doublebooking = TRUE;
  }

  if(!$doublebooking){
    $this->db->insert('ushers', $field);
    print("Succesfully uploaded roster for week: ".$field['Date']);
  }else{
    print("Some ushers are already rostered onto the worship team on ".$field['Date']);
  }
}else{
  print("The is already a ushers roster for ".$field['Date'].".");
  print("<br>");
}
```

I'm aware it isn't the best solution to the problem, it was the last resort due to getting this same issue.
The error is currently on the line containing

```php
$sql .= " OR worship.".(string)$column." = '".(string)$usher."'";
```

Its probably a simple problem, but I've been hitting my head on it for 5 or 6 hours now.

Comment: Please, format your code.

Comment: sorry about that, I removed formating trying to get it to stop telling me i had unformatted code.. forgot to put it back in after.

Comment: Dump both variables `$column` and `$usher` with `var_dump()` to see if they are already strings or not. Simply converting them to strings is not the best solution if they are arrays.

Comment: Not sure how to interpret var_dump, still figuring parts of php out:
string(4) "Date" array(7) { ["Team"]=> string(1) "1" ["Head_Usher"]=> string(10) "Tahi Hoera" ["Usher1"]=> string(10) "Brian Boyd" ["Usher2"]=> string(9) "Elsa Boyd" ["Usher3"]=> string(12) "Annette Tate" ["Usher4"]=> string(11) "Rob Vaughan" ["Usher5"]=> string(12) "Hellen Chuma" }

Comment: i think that means usher is an array. how would the column be a string "String(4) "Date"" and the usher be an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$usher` is an array, I think you'll find. `$ushers` is an array of arrays. `$usher` will will be an array with one field for each column in the ushers table. You probably want `$usher['name']` or `$usher['id']` something like that. Couldn't tell exactly what from the info.